# How to Change the format of values of a column using powershell?

Tags: javascript, powershell, csv

How to Change the 'n' number of timestamp in the joined_on column from `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` to `DD-MM-YYYY HH:SS` from an imported csv file using powershell scripting and how to save the result as new csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a CSV like this:

```
Name,Date,Colour
Alice,1997-05-13T21:50:00,Red
Bob,2001-06-03T10:52:36,Green
Carol,1991-12-21T02:25:45,Blue
```

You can convert the `Date` column as per your requirements with something like this in PowerShell:

```
Import-Csv .\Data.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Date = (Get-Date $_.Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:ss")
        $_
    } | Export-Csv .\Data2.csv
```

Which give output like this (if you re-import with `Import-Csv`):

```
Name  Date             Colour
----  ----             ------
Alice 13-05-1997 21:00 Red   
Bob   03-06-2001 10:36 Green 
Carol 21-12-1991 02:45 Blue
```

**NOTE**: This output is as you requested (`DD-MM-YYYY HH:SS`), which has `hours:seconds` in it.  I guess you meant `hours:minutes`, which you can get by changing the `ToString()` pattern to:

`dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`

Answer (score 2):

Cast your column to a `[datetime]` and then use `.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")`

```
> ([datetime]"2018-06-03T12:22:23").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
03-06-2018 12:22
```